# Match Projection & Extent Using GDAL

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I am looking to match both the projection and extent of two separate .tif files. The file I want all other .tif files introduced into raster calculations is as follows:

[image]

The other raster image covers the globe, however I am only interested in matching the extent of the first image, this second raster image looks like the following:

[image]

I attempted to reproject both rasters to the WGS 84 coordinate system (EPSG:4326) through the following GDAL code, however when I placed both rasters into QGIS to verify they were matched up, the second image was in the bottom left hand corner of the first, which verified my suspicion the code did not work as intended.

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -overwrite gfs.tif gfstest.tif`

Other info I can provide from this is the layer extent of both images, which I hope can provide some clues: 
Image 1:-1269.8514999999999873,-1269.8515000003390014 : 5446393.0834999997168779,3495901.1794999996200204

Image 2: -0.1250000000000000,-90.1250000000000000 : 359.8750000000000000,90.1250000000000000

Comment: Try reprojecting your gfs tif using the Reproject tool in QGIS. I believe it also just calls GDAL, but it's a quick and easy check to make sure you called it properly (with the right inputs/outputs). Also, there is a "Clip raster by extent" tool in QGIS (it's also just a gdal tool) that might do what you want in one command. I'm not sure if the rasters need to be in the same CRS for that tool to work; but if so, just use the reproject tool first.